# Waveshare 7'' LCD conflicts with WIFI (hostapd)

Tags: touchscreen, driver, input-device, hostapd

I have bought a Waveshare 7'' LCD (C) (https://www.waveshare.com/7inch-HDMI-LCD-C.htm) and it seems to work correctly on Raspberry PI 3B+ following the instructions on the site (it doesn't require specific drivers, just some parameters to add to `/boot/config.txt`). 
The problem I have is that it seems interfering with embedded Wifi card on Raspberry Pi and in particular with hostapd process.
I installed latest Raspian stretch (4.14.79) and Hostapd 2.4. If I keep the touchscreen USB cable plugged hostapd doesn't work well (wifi is not visible at all or it's visible but I can't connect). There is no error in the hostapd logs / kernel messages. If I unplug the screen access point works perfectly.
Do you have any idea where should I start to check to solve this issue?

P.S.: it's not a power issue since I'm using a 5V 4A PSU and I've checked that the current absorption by the screen is minimal (0.3 A).

Comment: Don't tell me why, but I discovered that after connecting the screen, wifi channels 7,8,9 cannot be used!